# I can't properly float divs

Tags: html, css

So I have to make an template of website which should look like 
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA8xN.png)
But I have problem with floating div's. I have to make like three div's
1: "global" div which is called 1 on upper picture that I linked
2: it's just an menu
3: is div which should display some text by clicking on menu articles

For now,my template looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Ade.png). How I may set those two div's (red, and yellow one) in same line?

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

#baner {
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
}

#zawartosc {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 60%;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="baner">
  <img src="baner.jpg" width="30%" height="60%" />

  <div id="menu">
    MENU</br>
    Opis</br>
    Jaka to liczba?</br>
    Liczby całkowite z wykresu
  </div>
  <div id="zawartosc">asd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a parent div.

```css
body{
    background-color:green;
}
#baner{
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}

.bottom{
  width:100%;
  position:relatvie;
}

#menu{
    background-color:red;
    width:40%;
    height:30%;
    float:left;

}
#zawartosc{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:60%;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="baner">
  <img src = "baner.jpg" width="30%" height="60%"/>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div id="menu">
      MENU</br>
      Opis</br>
      Jaka to liczba?</br>
      Liczby całkowite z wykresu
    </div>
   
    <div id="zawartosc">asd</div>
    
    </div>

  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
.left{
width:50%;
height:50px;
background-color:green;
float:left;text-align:center;
}
.right{
width:50%;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">hello</div>
<div class="left">green</div>
<div class="right">red</div>
```

for next div you should clear the floats using `clear:both`

Answer (score 0):

If you just float #zawartosc then it will start new line because before this there is a block level element (#menu) which will take whole available width. So you have to float both #menu and #zawartosc div if you want both in same line. Notice that img element is inline element. so if you dont use a wrapper of floating element then you have to set img element to display block

```css
body{
    background-color:green;
}
#baner{
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
#menu{
    background-color:red;
    width:40%;
    height:30%;

}
#zawartosc{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:60%;
    height:70px;
}
#menu,#zawartosc {
 float:left;
 
} 
img {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "baner">
<img src = "baner.jpg" width="30%" height="60%"/>

<div id = "menu">
 MENU</br>
 Opis</br>
 Jaka to lic
 zba?</br>
 Liczby całkowite z wykresu
</div>
<div id = "zawartosc">asd</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If use a wrapper div then you don't set img element to display block. Like this

```css
body{
    background-color:green;
}
#baner{
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
#menu{
    background-color:red;
    width:40%;
    height:30%;

}
#zawartosc{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:60%;
    height:70px;
}
#menu,#zawartosc {
 float:left;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "baner">
<img src = "baner.jpg" width="30%" height="60%"/>

<div class = 'wrapper'>
  <div id = "menu">
 MENU</br>
 Opis</br>
 Jaka to lic
 zba?</br>
 Liczby całkowite z wykresu
</div>
<div id = "zawartosc">asd</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Css has moved on from using floats to position things to the left and right (plus floats were only ever designed to be used for positioning images within text but where abused for a lack of a better way to position things)

Instead of floating your divs, I would use flexbox - this also has the added benefit that your left and right divs will become equal height:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

#baner {
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  
  display:flex; /* this is optional, but I added it to make the container below fill the vertical space */
  flex-direction:column; /* aligns children in a column */
}

.container {
  display:flex;  /* add this so menu and zawartosc are aligned in a row - default flex direction is row */
  flex-grow:1;   /* this just says fill the resat of the space - in this case the vertical space of baner */
}


#menu {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;   /* this can be a fixed width if you want - menus don't usually grow in size so best to make the content column fluid rather than both content and menu */
}

#zawartosc {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;  /* make this grow to fill the rest of the row */
}
```

```html
<div id="baner">
  <img src="baner.jpg" width="30%" height="60%" />

  <div class="container"> <!-- wrap below divs in a container -->
    <div id="menu">
      MENU</br>
      Opis</br>
      Jaka to liczba?</br>
      Liczby całkowite z wykresu
    </div>
    <div id="zawartosc">asd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[More information about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Useful Flexbox playground Codepen](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv)

If you want to continue using floats, then you either have to float the menu left, or move zawartosc before menu in your html - but don't forget to clear your floats too (probably why you have added a fixed height to baner)